# Java Jar ClassNotFoundException even though dependent library exists

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I am creating a (Minecraft) Forge mod that uses the (unofficial) Discord API, JDA. I am doing this in the Eclipse IDE.

In the IDE, I can add the JDA with dependencies just fine and get no errors in my code. Then, using gradlew and compiling it, I get an error when I try running it (in Minecraft).

I had a few people check my build.gradle to make sure it was correct, and it is. I'm assuming at this point that it is a general Java error.

Anyways, the error:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/nio/reactor/IOReactorException
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.prepareRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:151)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:131)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asString(BaseRequest.java:56)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.requests.Requester.toObject(Requester.java:100)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.requests.Requester.post(Requester.java:55)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.entities.impl.JDAImpl.login(JDAImpl.java:152)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.JDABuilder.buildAsync(JDABuilder.java:272)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.JDABuilder.buildBlocking(JDABuilder.java:307)
    at com.scarabcoder.ereijan.gui.GuiLogin.connect(GuiLogin.java:168)
    at com.scarabcoder.ereijan.gui.GuiLogin.func_146284_a(GuiLogin.java:143)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.func_73864_a(GuiScreen.java:466)
    at com.scarabcoder.ereijan.gui.GuiLogin.func_73864_a(GuiLogin.java:128)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.func_146274_d(GuiScreen.java:554)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.func_146269_k(GuiScreen.java:523)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71407_l(Minecraft.java:1674)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71411_J(Minecraft.java:1024)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:349)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launchWithMainClass(OneSixLauncher.java:310)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launch(OneSixLauncher.java:395)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.listen(EntryPoint.java:170)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.nio.reactor.IOReactorException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:106)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 32 more
```

And inside the jar file:
[image: The path to the "missing" class (it exists)]

Any help??

Comment: Sharing your manifest file may help in identifying the root cause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the problem actually lies with MinecraftForge, not necessarily due to a bug but actually due to a protection that Forge implemented.

Forge has full control over loading the classes of a mod and it specifically checks the package information of every class it loads against a set of restricted package paths to protect its own dependencies from accidentally being overwritten by loading a different version of a similar dependency. In this case, Forge uses a few Apache libs, so it prevents the loading of classes from the `org.apache` package namespace.

Thus, when loading the classes of your mod, Forge notices that these classes come from `org.apache` and chooses to specifically not load them. This means that when the `Unirest` dependency used by `JDA` attempts to use the Apache dependencies it relies on, they don't exist, and you encounter the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

The best way to deal with this is to properly shade your dependencies. Considering you're using Forge, you are most likely using Gradle. MinecraftForge actually has a guide on how to properly shade your dependencies [here](https://forgegradle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/shading/).

Comment: link is dead, archive here https://web.archive.org/web/20190806045834/https://forgegradle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/shading/

and relevant Forge discussion here https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/36791-trying-to-shade-dependencies-into-jar/

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError - is due to the class file that your code depends on is present at compile time but not found at runtime. Check your build and runtime classpaths.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the dependencies of your Discord API to your project should fix the problem.  Using the shaided Jar for your API may also work.